# MutableLiveData triggered twice? Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

I am using from `MutableLiveData` for connect to `API`, for first time it work true but for second time call twice.**(my observe call twice)**

Here is my `Fragment`:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
     ....
    quizViewModel.getLoginH5P()
    quizViewModel.loginH5P.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { response ->
        when (response) {
            is Resource.Success -> {
                hideProgressBar()
                response.data?.let {
                    Log.i("MYTAG", "AL " + it.loginurl!!)
                }
            }
            is Resource.Error -> {
                hideProgressBar()
                response.message?.let {
                    Log.i("MYTAG", "AP " + it)
                }
            }

            is Resource.Loading -> {
                showProgressBar()
                Log.i("MYTAG", "AT ")
            }
        }
    }
 .......
}
```

And Here is My `viewModel`:

```
class QuizViewModel(
    private val getQuizUseCase: GetQuizUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    val loginH5P: MutableLiveData<Resource<LoginH5PEntity>> = MutableLiveData()
    fun getLoginH5P() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        loginH5P.postValue(Resource.Loading())
        try {
            val apiResult = getQuizUseCase.execute()
            loginH5P.postValue(apiResult)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            loginH5P.postValue(Resource.Error(e.message.toString()))
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `impl`:

```
override suspend fun getLoginH5P(): Resource<LoginH5PEntity> {
    return responseToResource(quizRemoteDatasource.getQuiz())
}


private fun responseToResource(response: Response<LoginH5PEntity>): Resource<LoginH5PEntity> {
    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        response.body()?.let { result ->
            return Resource.Success(result)
        }
    }
    return Resource.Error(response.message())
}
```

And here is my custom `Resource`:

```
sealed class Resource<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val message: String? = null
) {
    class Success<T>(data: T) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Loading<T>(data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String, data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data, message)
}
```

I get my result twice:  `Log.i("MYTAG", "AL " + it.loginurl!!)`

Comment: Where do you call `getLoginH5P`

Comment: @GHH, I called it in onCreateView.

Comment: `onCreatView` only work once, how do you call `getLoginH5P` second time.

Comment: I get my result twice: Log.i("MYTAG", "AL " + it.loginurl!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is necessarily the reason for your issue, but you do need to fix it. Your ViewModel has a longer lifespan than the Fragment, but you're re-fetching the data and posting it to the LiveData all over again each time the Fragment recreates the view. You can simply fetch the data once when the ViewModel is created using the `liveData` builder. The code is simpler using the `liveData` builder anyway.

```
class QuizViewModel(
    private val getQuizUseCase: GetQuizUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    val loginH5P: LiveData<Resource<LoginH5PEntity>> = liveData {
        emit(Resource.Loading())
        try {
            emit(getQuizUseCase.execute())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            emit(Resource.Error(e.message.toString()))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It good work now, but I need call API when I coming to fragment. It just call API just once, when I coming to fragment don't call it again.

Comment: How are you getting your ViewModel reference? Using the Activity (a shared ViewModel)?

Comment: I am using from BottomNavigationView in Activity.

Comment: I Edited your response like bellow and it good work now.(you can edit your response and I accepted it). In viewModel:     fun loginH5Pd()  = liveData {
        
        emit(Resource.Loading())
        try {
            
            emit(getQuizUseCase.execute())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            emit(Resource.Error(e.message.toString()))
        }
    }

Comment: And in fragment: val responseLiveData = quizViewModel.loginH5Pd()
        responseLiveData.observe(activity!!, Observer {
            when (it) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    hideProgressBar()
                    it.data?.let {
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    hideProgressBar()
                    it.message?.let {
                    }
                }

                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    showProgressBar()
                }
            }
        })